# How do I run a single test in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm going through the [scala labs](https://github.com/scala-labs/scala-labs) and I can't seem to figure out how to run a single test.

I run `test` in `sbt` and I get 23 failing tests for me to fix. I want to run just the HelloWorldExercise.scala. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sbt "testOnly HelloWorldExercise"